# Pop up modal (fixed) appearing behind header and footer on safari

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, z-index, fixed

Seems like a decent amount of people have had this issue but I tried everything I've read with no luck...

I have a contact form pop up modal form (fixed) which works perfect on Chrome, mozilla, IE. When I open it on safari (mobile, ipad, mac, etc) It is fixed so when I scroll up or down it ends up going behind the top header and the footer. The screen size isn't high enough to increase the margins and even when I do this, scrolling still shows it behind the header/footer elements.

Seems like safari does not like fixed elements, I tried z-index (setting footer and header to 0 and even -1 and setting the modal much higher) which didn't work and I also tried -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)!important which many others seem to do but it does not do the trick. Is there something I am missing here? I unfortunately cannot provide a direct link to the site yet but I hope someone might be able to point me into the right direction.

Thanks a lot for the help!

```
HTML:
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span><h4>Form Title</h4>
    /* form goes here*/
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal{display:none;position:fixed;z-index:1;padding-top:100px;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
.modal-content{background-color:#fefefe;margin:auto;padding:20px;border:1px solid #888;width:80%;}

.modal{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:1050;display:none;overflow:hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;outline:0;}
.modal-content{position:relative;background-color:#fff;-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;background-clip:padding-box;border:1px solid #999;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius:6px;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);box-shadow:0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);}

div.widget.mod-inner div.mod-content ul{list-style:none;padding-left:0px;}
.single div.widget.mod-container.my_custom_widget-7.widget_my_custom_widget.clearfix .modal{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);padding-top:40px;overflow:auto;}
.single div.widget.mod-container.my_custom_widget-7.widget_my_custom_widget.clearfix .modal-content{max-width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;padding:20px;}
```

Just added the code. I tried to remove everything not relevant (please forgive me I am not too good with this stuff) 
Please let me know if I am not adding this code correctly so I can fix it. Again, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: We need to see some code if there's any hope of finding a solution to your specific problem.

Comment: Need a code-pen or fiddle of your working example please

Comment: I apologize here is the working form in fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/L7cofe4z/ Thanks again